# How to remove date format

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following content in the file. I would like to remove dates and the underlines from the file using sed. let me know if this would be possible to do with grep either.

```
03-02-2016
===========

<exp2://Ticket/26727777> Splunk Onboarding for SSO Components (UAT)

<exp2://Ticket/25709048> <SERVER-SETUP>Splunk Setup 14xMDN, 10xPRN Prod 

<exp2://Ticket/26716590> Logs not populated properly from all servers -  SPLUNK TEST

<exp2://Ticket/23995808> Prod: Create summary index summary_rover_lifecycle in DS cluster

05-02-2016
===========

<exp2://Ticket/26781310> Request for on-boarding on Splunk -Employee Systems Logs

<exp2://Ticket/26781558> Splunk setup for Apple Learn UAT hosts
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question so we can see the text. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: I fixed some of it. Are the blank lines actually part of your text file? Also, please show us your desired output so we know exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to GNU `grep`:

```
grep -vP '^(\d+-\d+-\d+|=+)$' file
```

And, if you don't:

```
grep -vE '^([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|=+)$' file
```

Both commands use grep's `-v` flag which means "print lines that don't match the pattern and look for lines consisting of either 3 groups of digits separated by dashes or one or more `=` from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the line.

You can do the same thing in `sed` with:

```
sed -E '/([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|=+)/d' file
```

Comment: Yes, it did work, can it be done using sed command?

Comment: @Sai sure, see updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, sed did work as well. This is printing the output. How do we make the changes effect in the file without printing?

Comment: @Sai use `sed -i `. Also, please remember to accept this answer if it solved your issue. That way, the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: I tried using sed -i option but it hasn’t effected the file with the changes what i was looking for. I tried with sed -in as well it did not pop any error but file did not get change. Can you have a look into it?

sed -i '/([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|=+)/d' sr
sed: 1: "sr": unterminated substitute pattern

Comment: @Sai you need both `-E` and `-i` and the right format. Try this: `sed -i -E '/([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|=+)/d' file`

Comment: How to print only the ticket number per the question posted.

26727777

23995808

Comment: @Sai what do you mean? The question posted doesn't ask for the ticket number, it asks to remove the `=====` and dates. If you now want to print only the ticker number, please post a separate question about that.